# React - Unable to click or type in input form using react-tagsinput and react-mailcheck

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input

I am using `react-tagsinput`, `react-input-autosize`, and `react-mailcheck` to create input tags that also suggests the right domain when the user misspell it in an email address.

I have gotten the `react-tagsinput` to work with `react-input-autosize` but when added with `react-mailcheck` my input form does not work at all, the form is un-clickable and unable to type and text into the field. I'm not getting any errors in the console and i'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I followed what they did in the `react-mailcheck` documentation: https://github.com/eligolding/react-mailcheck. I was hoping someone could look at it with a fresh pair of eyes to see what I am missing that is making it not work.

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TagsInput from 'react-tagsinput';
import AutosizeInput from 'react-input-autosize';
import MailCheck from 'react-mailcheck';


class EmailInputTags extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { tags: [], inputText: '' };

       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       this.handleInputText = this.handleInputText.bind(this);
       this.renderInput = this.renderInput.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(tags) {
        this.setState({ tags });
    }

    handleInputText(e) {
        this.setState({ inputText: e.target.value });
    }

    renderInput({ addTag, ...props }) {
        const { ...other } = props;
        return (
            <MailCheck email={this.state.inputText}>
                {suggestion => (
                    <div>
                        <AutosizeInput
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.inputText}
                            onChange={this.handleInputText}
                            {...other}
                        />
                        {suggestion &&
                        <div>
                            Did you mean {suggestion.full}?
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                )}
            </MailCheck>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { label, name } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="input-tag-field">
                <TagsInput inputProps={{ placeholder: '', className: 'input-tag' }} renderInput={this.renderInput} value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EmailInputTags;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this out.

Try passing as a prop to TagsInput the `onChange` function.

ie

```
{... onChange={(e) => {this.setState(inputText: e.target.value}}
```

Comment: thanks, that helps a bit! i can console.log that when i type something and press enter. but none of the stuff i need with the packages work.

Comment: @applechips, see the updated response.

since you're passing `this.state.inputText` to mail check,

You need to update that state in your `onChange`